# ckeditor - how to do an onchange from the editor to a php function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ckeditor

I need to call a php function from I suspect an ajax call. I have ckeditor and need to trap any keyboard movement and think onchange will do that. I then need to run a function to stop a timeout from happening, as I suspect the program can timeout if the user is staying in the editor too long.

`<textarea required cols='80' rows='9' class='ckeditor' name='email_text_editor' id='email_text_editor1' placeholder='Body text' onchange='updateTimer(this.value);'><?PHP print $email_subs_rem; ?> </textarea>


                                function updateTimer(myValue) {
                                    //sessionTimeoutUpdate();// php function
                                    //console.log(myValue);
                                    //$.ajax({
                                    //    type: "GET",
                                    //    url: "dummy.php",
                                    //    data: "mainid =" + id,
                                    //    success: function(result) {
                                    //        $("#somewhere").html(result);
                                    //    }
                                    //});
                                }
                            </script>`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this...

```
function updateTimer(myValue) {
     //sessionTimeoutUpdate();// php function
     console.log(myValue);
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "dummy.php",
         data: {"mainid =" + id, action : "updateSession"},
         success: function(result) {
           $("#somewhere").html(result);
         }
       });
     }
```

PHP file

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_GET['mainid'])){
      if($_GET['action']== "updateSession"){
          sessionTimeoutUpdate();//function you wanna call
      }
   }
   
   function sessionTimeoutUpdate(){
      //Do your task here
      //After done
      echo "done";
   }
?>
```

Since there is no way you can directly call a php function at client side without request, AJAX is very useful here.

Comment down for any queries.